# Synchronizing signature from desktop GMail to Android GMail app

Tags: gmail

I need to send email from road and want my professional signature to appear. Our company policy requires use of "real" signature when using mobile email and I can't adhere to my own policy.

How do I sync my desktop GMail signature in Android? It works on my employees' iPhones, but I couldn't figure it out how to do that in Android. I know I can type a signature in, but it's just not the same as what appears on our desktops.

Comment: any updates in 2021?

Answer (score 4):

The feature you are looking for is not available with the Gmail app (yet). ([source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gmail/ioJwjWJKW1Y)). You can't even add any type of rich-text signature to your mobile app. Devs say that this feature is still being worked on. The only option available to you is to add a simple text signature through the app.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing; I thought I just couldn't figure it out.  Thanks for the answer.  Seems like such a simple feature.  I thought for sure that since it works on the iphones it must work on a google phone....hope they fix it soon.  Thanks again.

Comment: any updates in 2021?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I use is one of the Labs features: Canned responses.

On my Android device I then use an app called "Responses" that takes your canned responses from the associated Gmail account and copies it to your clipboard.

You then just paste it into your email. You can even have images, etc., in the canned responses.